# Is there a cloudwatch equivalent for prometheus Counter?

Tags: counter, prometheus, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics

I need to be able to atomically increment (or decrement) a metric value in cloudwatch (and also be able to reset it to zero).  Prometheus provides a Counter type that allows one to do this; is there an equivalent in cloudwatch?  All I'm able to find is a way to add a new sample value to a metric, but not increment or decrement it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

CloudWatch is like a TSDB. It stores point-in-time values. You can't mutate a metric value once it is ingested. See [Publishing Metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html). Also, I don't think storing a counter in CloudWatch will be very useful. There is no `rate(...)` function in CloudWatch like in Prometheus. The best you can do is store the deltas and use the `sum` [statistic with a period](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/US_SingleMetricPerInstance.html). Here is an e.g. assuming metrics are ingested at 1m granularity

| Time | Counter | rate(5m) | CW metric | sum with period 5m |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1m | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2m | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 |
| 3m | 20 | 20 | 10 | 20 |
| 4m | 40 | 40 | 20 | 40 |
| 5m | 50 | 50 | 10 | 50 |
| 6m | 60 | 60 | 10 | 60 |
| 7m | 100 | 90 | 40 | 90 |

Note that metrics can be ingested at finer granularity but it comes at a cost. Also, the statistics (Sum,Average,Maximum,Minimum etc) can be retrieved only at 1 minute granularity. There is an option to retrieve the raw data when retrieving a statistic but not sure what would be the use of doing so.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems like a useful trick.

Answer (score 0):

CloudWatch now supports metric math which includes support for the rate function, defined as:

"Returns the rate of change of the metric per second. This is calculated as the difference between the latest data point value and the previous data point value, divided by the time difference in seconds between the two values."

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html